# Can Call Objective C didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method again? Is it leads for rejection?

Tags: ios, restart

Can we call `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` again in app, in order to restart whole app for some language settings. My concern is for app rejection. Do we have anyone who have any app approved using manual calling of this function?

Comment: Why do you want to restart the app? Can't you just pop to root viewcontroller and dump all the session data?

Comment: Thanks @NSNoob, I have already made the changes accordingly and its working fine. I was using didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method previously which is wrong from memory leak point of view. Just asking for curiosity, if anyone did this silly thing ever and got approval.